# Add new record to subform with same ID

Tags: vba, ms-access, relationships, subform

I have an Access 2007 DB that tracks tickets. There is a Parent table/form and Child table/form. Parent table houses owner info and Child table houses ticket info. It is a 1 to Many relationship. (Many tickets to 1 owner). There is a sub form that is clickable on the Parent form and opens the Child form. The ID field in the sub form is hyperlinked to the child form. HOWEVER, I am unable to open different records by clicking the sub form. The subform only opens the first record with that ID.

Comment: Please show code or macro behind button. Consider using multiple item/continuous form or data sheet for child table.

Comment: Here is the code that opens the Child form.                                       Private Sub ID_Click()
Dim varWhereClause As String
varWhereClause = "ID = " & Me!ID
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmticket-CHILD", , , varWhereClause
End Sub
The fields in the subform that are in view are ID, Category, Ticket Violation, Date Issued. Thank you.